# ¿Cómo poder hacerlo correctamente una tabla con bootstrap en HTML?

Tags: html, bootstrap, html-tabla

Muy buenas, estoy tratando de tomar el ejemplo en [este link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_contextual&stacked=h)

Lo que yo trato es establecer colores como en esta imagen: [image: el ejemplo]

Después de comprender la tabla que hice crear a mi modo, tratando de hacer una tabla en plantillas utilizando bootstrap pero por alguna razón no funciona, como muestra en esta imagen:

[image: el error de tabla]

El código de la tabla es [este link](https://jsfiddle.net/h7cL428g/)

Aunque estoy utilizando HTML, no sé cual es la causa la verdad. Espero sus respuestas.

Comment: añade por favor el código involucrado aquí; además se mas claro en que deseas lograr y lo que obtienes al momento para que la comunidad comprenda de que hablas

Comment: esta página no me deja añadir más del código, porque es extenso. Por eso dejé el link del código de la tabla.  trataré de editar.

Comment: @αλρθα traté lo que más pude, sigue siendo código extenso. pero dejé más explicaciones.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es añadir colores a la tabla? ¿Ese es tu problema?

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar sobre la propiedad [background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) o ir directamente a [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS) que te servirá para aclarar muchas de tus dudas.

Comment: @JheymanMejia utilizando css dentro del html? pero siguiendo el ejemplo en la tabla del w3schools debería leerse correctamente. (utilicé otro nombre, que es el tr class, no div class)

Comment: Por eso, ¿qué es lo que quieres lograr? Las clases, independientemente si están en un `tr` o un `div`, van a aplicar unas propiedades definidas en tu CSS. Si sólo usas los estilos de Bootstrap entonces debes ir allí y modificar los colores de esas clases (cosa que no recomiendo). Puedes editar tu pregunta si necesitas aclarar o añadir más información.

Comment: Al final creo que lo resolví, añadiendo otro link rel del jquery del bootstrap (ése fue la causa real, sin añadirlo, contiene errores), pero creando otro archivo del css para dar forma al html y de poco logré tener la forma de la tabla como quería. Me costó comprenderlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpen por no responder a mi situación, creo que resolví por si mismo, como ordenar correctamente la tabla utilizando reset 1.0 de css y a través de html con bootstrap actualizado con el icono de fontawesome  (los link href).

Adjunto mi código, espero poder compartirlo con los demás para comprender.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
<title>Tabla plan</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style type="text/css">

   /* RESET CSS v1.0*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
 outline: 0;
}

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
 text-decoration: none;
}
del {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* FIN RESETEO */

table, tbody, thead, tr, th, td {
 text-align: left !important;
}

.fa, .fas {
 font-weight: 900;
 float: right;
}

table {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 border-collapse:  collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.table td, .table th{
 padding: .75rem;
 vertical-align: top;
 border-top: 1px solid #92a3b4;
}

.style-simple table:not(.recaptchatable) th {
    background: 0 0;
        background-color: rgba(63, 191, 191, 0);
}

body {
 font-size:  15px;
 line-height: 19px;
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.back {
 background: #87CEEB ;
 background-color: skyblue ;
}

.blue {
 color: blue;
 float: right;
}

  </style> 
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container" style="width: 60%;">
 <table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr class="info back">
   <td>Licenciamiento de ABZ Renumeraciones</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
   <td>Setup y carga de información</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Implementacion y puesta en marcha</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Actualizaciones de parámetros legales, laborales y previsionales</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Generación de archivo previred para pago de leyes sociales</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Generación de nómina bancaria</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Generación de declaraciones juradas de sueldos</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Contratos, anexos y finquitos desde ABZ</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Multiempresa y multiusuario</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Dashboard con reqportes de gestión y operativos personalizables</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Control de vacaciones, licencias y préstamos de empleados</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Asistente para cálculos complejos</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Centralización de sueldos según plan de cuentas de la contabilidad</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Workflow de remuneraciones con designación de responsables</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Portal empresa para gerencia y socios</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Portal empresa para gerencia y socios</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Soporte telefónico y vía correo electrónico ilimitado</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Carpeta laboral digital del trabajador</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>             
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr class="info back">
   <td>Licenciamiento ABZ Remuneraciones</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Almacenamiento 100% cloud</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Seguridad de la información</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Consolidación de la información</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr class="info back">
   <td>Integraciones Especiales</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Integración con sistemas de control de asistencia (API)</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Integración con sistemas contables (API)</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Migración de información histórica</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Desarrollos especiales</td>
  <td>
   <i class="fas fa-check blue"></i>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
 <br>    
</body>
</html>
```

Mi idea con div container fue una mala elección, asi que pensaba crear una tabla asi.
Gracias a todos por la ayuda con sus comentarios.